# "Abstract Error" shows up when calling methods from child classes

Tags: delphi

I want to instantiate classes based on a parameter. Both classes are derived from TSample so I define my code as:

```
var T: TSample;
```

then I do

```
T := TMySample.Create;
```

or

```
T := TYourSample.Create;
```

and calling `T.Hello` gives an "Abstract Error".

```
type TSample = class
     public
       procedure Hello; virtual; abstract;
     end;

     TMySample = class(TSample)
     public
       procedure Hello;
     end;

     TYourSample = class(TSample)
     public
       procedure Hello;
     end;

...

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var T: TSample;
    a: Integer;
begin
  if a = 1 then T := TMySample.Create
  else          T := TYourSample.Create;

  T.Hello;      //Abstract Error here
  T.Free;
end;

procedure TMySample.Hello;
begin
  showmessage('My');
end;

procedure TYourSample.Hello;
begin
  showmessage('Your');
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to declare the overridden methods as, well, overridden:

```
 TMySample = class(TSample)
 public
   procedure Hello; override; // <--
 end;

 TYourSample = class(TSample)
 public
   procedure Hello; override; // <--
 end;
```

Actually, the compiler warned you about this, but you didn't listen :)

```
[dcc32 Warning] Unit1.pas(25): W1010 Method 'Hello' hides virtual method of base type 'TSample'
[dcc32 Warning] Unit1.pas(30): W1010 Method 'Hello' hides virtual method of base type 'TSample'
```

---

Also, you probably already know this, but there are two issues with your sample code:

1. Since local variables of non-managed types are not initialized, the value of `a` is undefined.
2. You don't protect the `TSample` object, so you might leak resources. (In fact, in this case, you will due to the exception!)

Fixed:

```
  a := 123;
  if a = 1 then
    T := TMySample.Create
  else
    T := TYourSample.Create;

  try
    T.Hello;      //Abstract Error here
  finally
    T.Free;
  end;
```